# StackOverFlowException when using @html.Action()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am receiving a weird error message when i try and use @Html.Action() in my view?

here is the view code:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Clients")
```

And here is the controller:

```
public class ClientsController : Controller
{
    private ROUTING_DBV6Entities db = new ROUTING_DBV6Entities();

    // GET: Clients
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await db.Clients.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

And here is the error message which I have recieved:

```
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

Comment: Which controller/action is that View for?

Comment: Where are you calling `@Html.Action("Index", "Clients")`? Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613324/html-action-causes-a-stackoverflowexception) is your issue?

Comment: Is your view code located in Clients/Index ?

Comment: You have created an infinite loop. `@Html.Action("Index", "Clients")` calls the `ClientsController.Index` which then calls the View Index which then calls `@Html.Action("Index", "Clients")`. Maybe you wanted an action link.

Comment: Have a look at partials referencing Index, that might casue a never ending story.

Comment: @Aron that makes sense, all I want is the html url to put inside my A tag

Comment: @Zapnologica use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200476/html-actionlink-method

Comment: Side note: Do not forget to dispose your `ROUTING_DBV6Entities`.

Comment: @Silvermind Unless Zapnologica is taking the dangerous route of a shared context

Comment: it is recusively calling same action again and again

Comment: What I don't get is why is it calling it recursively? i'm not clicking on it? It should just render in the view? How do I get @Html.ActionLink  without it giving me the <a></a> element ?

Comment: @PaulZahra Indeed, then injection would be better :).

Comment: @Url.Action() was the one I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling this from _Layout.cshtml?

try returning a partial view - `return PartialView(await db.Clients.ToListAsync());`

or add this to the clients view 
`@{
    Layout = null;
}`